# Grunt does not seem to run my tasks when I save files

Tags: gruntjs

It seems that my tasks aren't running when I try to save files. I'm using the latest version of Grunt because I just installed it yesterday and my operating system is Windows 8.1. I'm new to grunt but I'm sure I've installed it correctly and followed every instruction on the Grunt website. Do I need to run a command or something so Grunt will have to actively watch the files and process the files?

Here is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    jshint: {
        scripts: {
            src: ['js/*.js']
        },
    },

    uglify: {
        scripts: {
            src: 'js/global.js',
            dest: 'js/global.min.js'
        }
    },

    less: {
        styles: {
            files: {
                'css/main.css': 'less/main.less'
            }
        }
    },

    watch: {
        scripts: {
            files: 'js/*.js',
            task: ['jshint','uglify']
        },
        styles: {
            files: 'less/**/*.less',
            task: 'less:styles'
        }
    }


});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'uglify', 'less']);


};
```

I don't see anything wrong with it so my problem is I still have to manually type 'grunt' in the command line to compile the files even though I have already set up watch. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tasks` property in the `watch` config is plural.

```
task: ['jshint','uglify']
```

should be

```
tasks: ['jshint','uglify']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the `tasks` property in the `watch` and I tried updating a file from my `js` folder. Still no automatic file processing going on. `watch` detects the file changes when i run `grunt watch` so this is very weird. i can't get it to work.

Comment: So I figured it out. You need to run `grunt watch` while working on the files. It wasn't on the grunt documentation :/. Thanks @Kyle